Tiny worms in blackberries
I picked blackberries in my yard, and I had to let them sit in a bowl on the counter for 1/2hour.When I came back there were tiny worms crawling on them.What are they?

I suppose a fair follow up is "are the berries safe to eat??"

That was my concern

Free protein, you'll be fine

I don't know about worms, but since I've been a child I've noticed home grown blackberries have lots of bugs crawling in them if you sit them in a bowl. We'd always wash a few times and not worry about it.
I'm sure I've eaten plenty of bugs in the ones I eat right off the bush :)

I was LK traumatized as a kid when eating mulberries from the tree only to discover little worms that look just like the natural "little hairs" on the fruit. Then, as an adult, I ate some from a grocery store to find the same!!! Probably bad luck, but I'm toast on them now. That being said, maybe soak in water with a teaspoon of salt? I never got sick, though, and I ate a LOT of them.

Blackberries are notorious for containing worms and extremely difficult to separate from the fruit, no matter which method of soaking is used.

Most likely fruit flies or any other insect laying eggs on fruit. I have sometimes seen the same with blueberries harvested at a nearby farm.
You can stay assured that you are not the only one waiting for fruits to be ripe in your garden.

Likely fruit fly larvae. Soak in salt water before eating (they come to the surface of the water). If you accidentally consume them, they die right away once it hits your tummy. They aren’t really dangerous at all but they can make the fruit turn bad.
